# How do I go about checking what component am I drawing in?

Tags: java, canvas, components

I write code accessing API, that is obfuscated, and I had no problems in drawing for example png image over the canvas.

For example:

```
g.drawImage(img2, 423, 314, null);
```

the problem starts when I try to draw a gif.
I need to specify the container, it seems, which is not the case in drawImage
I've been trying to do it this way:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("http://i.imgur.com/x.gif");
Graphics w = (Graphics) g;
// g is graphics2d, I have tried with both, both don't work (it compiles, but nothing appears)

imageIcon.paintIcon(this.getCanvas(), w, mouse.getPosition().x,
        mouse.getPosition().y);
```

but it simply refuses to draw anything, and doesn't give me any errors.
Once again, I am using client API, in which I don't have access to everything. I don't know what am I drawing on exactly, so I have no idea how to do this properly. Any idea on how to draw my gif without specifying the component, or how do I get the same component I am drawing on using the simple "draw"?

Comment: `it simply refuses to draw anything`  Unless you have an API that passes you the Graphics object of the component every time a component is painted you will lose the painting when swing determines the component needs to be painted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it was important. The API onPaint(Graphics 2D) function exists, and it passes me graphics2d as argument

Comment: Does your method get called continually or just once. That is if the frame gets resized you will need to repaint. Any event that causes component to be repainted should pass you the Graphics object. You probably should not be using an Icon since you should not need to know which component the Graphics object belongs to. Instead try using ImageIO to read the file as a BufferedImage and then just use the Graphics.drawImage(...) method.

Comment: it gets called continually. Frame is never resized (cannot be, I think). I will make an attempt on it now ;)

Comment: Both BufferedImage and Image worked, but it shows only the first frame of the GIF. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to animate a gif image using a Graphics object. I always use a JLabel with an ImageIcon containing the gif, which means you need to add the label to the frame. I'm still not really understanding your application so I don't think I have any more suggestions.